# Twig function for repeating template

Tags: symfony, twig, templating

I'm new to Twig and recently started a project. In this I use a Star Rating Display very often, which needs also some values, e.g the rating to display or the size.

Currently, I always use

```
<div class="ratingarea">
    {% include 'Artist:rating.html.twig' 
    with {'rating': artist.rating, 'size': 'medium' } %} 
</div>
```

everywhere, which does the job, but I was wondering, if there's the option to reduce this to a function that only takes the parameters and returns the desired template, something like this:

```
<div class="ratingarea"> {% rating(2.8, 'medium') %} </div>
```

Is this possible? Or another way to improve this?

This is the template:

```
<span>
  <div class="review-rating">
    <div class="rating {{size}}-rating">
      <div class="stars stars-fontawesome-o top-art">
        <select class="list-rating fontawesome-o " 
                 data-current-rating="{{rating}}">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rely on macro's,

<kbd>macro.twig</kbd>

```
{% macro rating(rating, size) %}
<span>
  <div class="review-rating">
    <div class="rating {{size}}-rating">
      <div class="stars stars-fontawesome-o top-art">
        <select class="list-rating fontawesome-o " data-current-rating="{{rating}}">
          {% for i in 1..5 %}
          <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</span>
{% endmacro %}
```

<kbd>template.twig</kbd>

```
{# import the macro's in the file "macro.twig" as the namespace `macro` #}
{% import "macro.twig" as macro %}
{{ macro.rating(2.5, 'medium') }}
```

[twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/58algu)

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely forgot macros and searched for everything else in the docs^^ Also nice use of the for loop